# Text Recognition failing to recognize currency symbols

Tags: android-vision

I am using the text recognition API within mobile vision, and trying to work with currency amounts. The OCR currently supports Latin based languages like French, German, etc., so I figured the country's currency (Euro) would be a recognized symbol, but as far as I can tell, it's not.

Are there language preferences that I should be changing in order to detect €? Does anyone have experience working with currency symbols within mobile vision as well, or is it just not currently supported?

Thanks!

Comment: Please tell us what you have done and Stackoverflow is a programmers community. Feel free to ask for any help on website like Quora.

Comment: I'm familiar with stackoverflow, I'm a programmer. This question belongs on stackoverflow, and it includes the "android-vision" tag, so I'm targeting those that are also using the mobile vision API for android, and have some familiarity with it. Thanks though @Nevermore!

Answer (score 2):

I also would like to know if the Google Mobile Vision API can be configured to recognize the € symbol.

With other OCRs, like Tesseract, you can specify a white list and a blacklist of characters - like only numbers, only text, or text, numbers and € symbol.

If this does not work with the Google Mobile Vision API, it is a major limitation, and it can't be used for many use cases.

Answer (score 0):

No it does not support recognizing symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Try set languageHints, it helped me with the same problem

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "image": {
        "source": {
          "gcsImageUri": "gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/YOUR_FILE_NAME"
        }
      },
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "TEXT_DETECTION"
        }
      ],
      "imageContext": {
        "languageHints": [
          "en", "fr"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```