# How to detect ¥ yen symbol in Firebase Google cloud OCR text recognition?

Tags: firebase-mlkit, text-recognition

I am using Firebase Google cloud text recognition OCR. Where I am scanning text and currency. In this case I am easily able to scan text however, some symbols such as yen ¥ is not detected.

I am scanning text with firebase google cloud ocr API service in app.

Comment: try see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61161828/3123272

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Cloud Vision API in ML Kit, you can use the Document Text API or the "dense" option for the non-Latin alphabet support.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/recognize-text#document_text