# Google Cloud Vision API fails to detect currency signs

Tags: ocr, google-cloud-vision, google-vision

I'm using Google Cloud Vision API to do OCR in images. Currency signs can prove to be very vital in solution to my problem

**Problem that I encountered**: Google Cloud Vision API fails to detect certain currency signs(Rupee(₹) in my case)

I tried running the API for this image in 2 ways
[image: Currency]

1. I wrote a python program for detection as per the reference: [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr#vision_text_detection-python)
   The output that I got
   `3. 己 AB 长 Rp CHF f Ft € も 元 Jy 手 le # 夫 %24`
   Clearly it is failing for some cases.
2. I tried the [demo](https://cloud.google.com/vision) available on the website.
   The output that I got
   `C A 요 한 ₹ Л В R p  * C 元 C H F } F t m 元`
   with the bounding boxes as

[image]

I expected them to have the same outputs. The second one is able to detect Ruppe sign(₹) which I need. I cannot use the demo version in my project. It needs to run on batch of images. Is there any workaround by which I can detect currency sign in the script also.

Comment: Can you post the json requests for each case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run it with Document_text_detection instead of text_detection

Comment: Yes. Worked! Thanks a lot

Comment: It has worked for my case. But just out of curiosity, do you have any idea about other currency signs? Take $ sign for the case, since it was unable to detect that even by using `document_text_detection` method

Comment: is it detected in the demo?

Comment: No not even in demo

Comment: Language hints may help a bit also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42653309/text-recognition-failing-to-recognize-currency-symbols